# (read-line) executing before preceing prinln

Tags: clojure

```
(do
  (print "Enter name: ")
  (let [name (read-line)]
    (println "Hello " name)))
```

Results in being prompted to enter my name, then the `print` and `println` statements are executed looking like this:

```
Enter name: Hello  stuart
=> nil
```

I tried `(flush)`

```
(do
  (print "Enter name: ")
  (flush)
  (let [name (read-line)]
    (println "Hello " name)))
```

But same thing happens, it always does the (read-line) before anything else!

I also tried

```
(doall (
  (print "Enter name: ")
  (flush)
  (let [name (read-line)]
    (println "Hello " name))))
```

But again this prompts for name first before anything else then throws an exception :(

Am I missing something obvious here?

:Note: This is running it via the repl.

If I try to just create an application with the following

```
(defn -main
  "I don't do a whole lot ... yet."
  [& args]
  (do
  (print "Enter your name: ")
  (flush)
  (let [s (read-line)]
    (println "You entered " s))))

(-main)
```

and run it, not via the repl it works as expected except it runs everything twice!

```
Enter your name: stuart
You entered  stuart
Enter your name: stuart
You entered  stuart

Process finished with exit code 0
```

If I remove the `(flush)`, it does things out of order, but still does them twice!

```
(defn -main
  "I don't do a whole lot ... yet."
  [& args]
  (print "Enter your name: ")
  (let [s (read-line)]
    (println "You entered " s)))

hfghfgh
Enter your name: You entered  hfghfgh
fghfgh
Enter your name: You entered  fghfgh

Process finished with exit code 0
```

What's going on!

This is all using lein

Comment: You don't need `(-main)`. `lein` does it anyway. That is why everything gets printed out twice.

Comment: @akond So it does, I didn't realise. I feel like a bit of an idiot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a limb here because I start work soon.

Are you running this via a REPL in IntelliJ+Cursive? If you are, one of the REPL configurations (the one that spawns a popup window to enter input) doesn't play nice with giving input to stdin. I'm not sure why, but I've been dealing with it for awhile. There's two configuration settings to choose from in "Edit Configurations...": "nREPL" (which I call "Full"), and "clojure.main" (which I call "Simple").

If I'm doing anything with stdin, I use Simple because Full has the odd behavior that you describe. Simple also loads faster from the start, but doesn't allow nice things like killing the current running task without killing the whole REPL.

To "fix" it, click the run configuration drop down near the top right, click "Edit Configurations", "+" in the top left, "Clojure REPL", "Local", then use the "clojure.main" option under "Which type of REPL to run:". Give it a name like "Simple" or something to differentiate it from the other configuration you're using.

---

And as @akond mentioned, you're getting things running twice if you're using `lein run` or a similar mechanism that calls `-main` for you. Having a top-level call to `-main` in the script isn't ideal anyway. It will force the whole script to run any time you load the file, which, if you're developing with a REPL, can be quite often. Best just to call `-main` in the REPL when you explicitly want it to run.

Comment: I am running with IntelliJ and Cursive, yes! THanks a lot for this!

Comment: @Stuart Ha, gotta love blind shots in the dark. And no problem. This frustrated me too when I first came across it.